# Remove a line of a csv or ignore it

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm using fast-csv to read csv files but the format of my files aren't exactly as expected for fast-csv:

```
First line with some details (not important)
Second line with header
Third line with data
Fourth line with data
...
```

And how i read it:

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const stream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.csv');
const csvStream = csv
    .fromStream(stream,
        {
            headers: true,
            delimiter: ',',
            rowDelimiter: '\n',
            quoteHeaders: false,
            quoteColumns: false
        })
    .on("data", data => {
       // i do something with datas

    })
    .on("error", error => {
        console.log("CSV is invalid !", error);
    })
    .on("end", data => {
        console.log("End of parsing");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The problem here is

> headers: true,

will looks for first line as headers that's why I want to remove first line or ignore it. How to do that ? (I know I can read the file and write the file without the first line but I don't think that's the proper way to do that...)

Versions: 
node v10.0.0 & fast-csv 5.6.0

---

Edit: Test with @Anders Carstensen example:

```
const file = 'myfile.csv';
const fs = require("fs");
const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
    encoding: 'utf8'
});

stream.on('readable', () => {
    // Read through the stream until we encounter a new line
    let chunk;
    while (null !== (chunk = stream.read(1))) {

        if (chunk == '\n'){
            console.log('line break');
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log('test');


    // CSV parsing
    const csvStream = csv.fromStream(stream,
    {
        renameHeaders: false,
        headers: true,
        delimiter: ',',
        rowDelimiter: '\n',
        quoteHeaders: false,
        quoteColumns: false
    })
    .on("data", data => {
        console.log(data);

    })
    .on("error", error => {
        console.log("CSV invalid !", error);
    })
    .on("end", data => {
        console.log("End of parsing");
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Output:

```
line break
test
line break
test
```

Edit2: Check @Anders Carstensen answer for the solution (problem was using .on and not .once)

Comment: from the docs: renameHeaders=false: If you want the first line of the file to be removed and replaced by the one provided in the headers option - Only to be used with headers=[String]

Comment: You are printing values instead of data over here as a result there is ref error from above code

Comment: @Margon It means it replaces the first line for another in headers option (you use this option when you have a wrong header as first line, not in my case). I already contact fast-csv and they told me it was impossible to do what I want with a fast-csv option, but thank's for trying :-)

Comment: @sreepurna Yes my bad when writing the post, I edited with the right version thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should chew through the part of the stream you don't want the parser to look at. Here I read until I have encountered the first new line (`\n`).

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    csv = require('fast-csv');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('c:\\temp\\test.csv', {
  encoding: 'utf8'
});

stream.once('readable', function () {
  // Read through the stream until we encounter a new line
  var chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = stream.read(1))) {
    if (chunk === '\n')
      break;
  }

  // Then do the CSV parsing
  const csvStream = csv
    .fromStream(stream,
      {
        headers: true,
        delimiter: ',',
        rowDelimiter: '\n',
        quoteHeaders: false,
        quoteColumns: false
      })
    .on("data", data => {
      // i do something with datas
      console.log('data', data);
    })
    .on("data-invalid", data => {
      console.log('invalid data', data);
    })
    .on("error", error => {
      console.log("Le fichier CSV est invalide !", error);
    })
    .on("end", data => {
      console.log("End of parsing");
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working: the csvStream never starts + it breaks two times (after first line and second line then nothing happend)

Comment: It works on my computer. Could you add to your original post how you created the `stream`?

Comment: Peculiar. I have added handling for "data-invalid" in my example above. Please try adding that. Could you also add to your original how you used to create `stream` (before integrating my example)? What is `file`?

Comment: It's just the differents require (I edited). I tried with data-invalid same thing (data-invalid is used to add some restrictions on datas I think)

Comment: The above code works on my machine on an utf8-encoded file that contains 4 lines - first line is junk, the next is the headers, and the next two are the data. I'm using NodeJS v6.10.3 and Windows. Unless you are in a similar environment, I am out of ideas. :(

Comment: node v10.0.0 & fast-csv 5.6.0 (+windows 10) for me. Can you please add your file ? I'd be curious to try it

Comment: I updated my NodeJS to v10 and could reproduce your bug. It seems that `readable` event gets fired multiple times. I'm only interested in the first time. So I've changed `stream.on('readable'` to `stream.once('readable'` .. Could you please try with this?